# Google Translate API language code for Brazilian Portuguese

Tags: api, google-translate

I am interesting in translating to Brazilian Portuguese. Based on the [google translate API document](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages), we only have "pt", which looks like Portugal Portuguese. Any suggestions on how to get Brazilian Portuguese via API ?

Answer (score 1):

From what [this document](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages) says, I think that the google API only has 1 type of Portugese.

They both appear on the same line as:

```
Portuguese (Portugal, Brazil)   pt
```

Comment: Maybe add a link to where you found this information. The answer is not supported in its current state

Comment: The link he attached cleary show that there only is 1 type of portugese...